# M.2 SSD is showing up in Windows but not in bios

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios, m.2

So basically title.
I've bought an M.2 SSD, plugged in, booted from main one and it is showing up in a disk manager.
Then I used easy partition to clone my system to a new SSD, everything went fine.
But I can't set an option to boot from a new one since it doesn't show up at all.

My mobo is Asus H97-pro an SSD I bought is  adata xpg gammix s5.

I would appreciate any help.

P.s. it wasn't showing up in bios before I cloned the system either

EDIT. My mobo firmware is latest that available on a official website

Comment: Do you have CSM enable or disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried both ways

Comment: Once I'm turning off the csm it doesn't show any drives that I have connected

Comment: Is your firmware updated?  Can you edit your question to include that information?

Comment: @Ramhound I've the latest available

Comment: Did you clone the partition or the entire disk?

Comment: Not clear on your setup. Do you have a M.2 SSD already and you connected the second one? If yes, can you try to take out the first one and put the new one in it's place and see if BIOS sees it?

Comment: @hidralisk I have a regular SSD and bought a new m.2 to try and use as a main one

Comment: @harrymc I cloned the entire disk

Answer (score 1):

After searching for information on this problem, I found that
this is a common problem with ASUS BIOS. It is caused by the fact that the
[ADATA XPG GAMMIX S5 SSD](https://www.adata.com/jo/feature/587)
is a PCIe disk and not a SATA disk, while ASUS BIOS tends to list only SATA drives
in the boot order.

As an NVMe drive, you will not find it listed by name alongside the other drives,
because it is not a SATA device. It is a PCIe device and so generally only visible by
name as a configurable hardware device inside of the BIOS when RAID is enabled.
If you are using AHCI, you may find BIOS settings for it (like 2X or 4X mode),
but not the device itself by name. Likewise, you generally don't see your other PCIe
devices like WiFi, NIC or GPU enumerated and identified by name in the BIOS.

You may examine your BIOS for options relating to NVMe drives.
There had been reports from some ASUS computers about an option to handle
PCIe as SATA, although I'm somewhat skeptical.
(Don't play too much with BIOS settings, as an error can be fatal.)

If you cannot find any useful option, you will have to accept the fact that
the M.2 disk is still perfectly usable, just not as a boot device.

However, while the UEFI boot partition needs to stay on its current disk,
you might be able to add the Windows on the M.2 as a boot option to the
boot menu, maybe even as the default.

The best tool for the job is the free version of
[EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)
(registration required), using the *Add New Entry* section:

[image]